# Validar select dinámico con jquery-validate y bootstrap en php

Tags: php, bootstrap, jquery-validate

Necesito validar un Select con jquery.validate y bootstrap antes de registrar, de lo contrario que mande la alerta. Tengo la tabla casa y la tabla apuesta, en el formulario selecciono es el id de la tabla casa para saber el nombre de la casa, y es ese selecc el que necesito validar. Ver imagen.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema se ve en la imagen 2, que después de seleccionar la casa de apuesta sigue validando como si no se hubiera seleccionado nada.
El código utilizado en el formulario es este:

```html
<form action="registrar_apuesta.php" method="GET" name="myform" id="myform">  
    <div class="row">                                                                                   
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="id_casa">Casa de Apuesta *:</label>
                <div class="input-group">    
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i>
                    </span> 
                    <select id="id_casa" class="form-control" name="id_casa">
                        <?php
                        $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'apuestas');
                        ?>
                        <option value="0">-- Seleccionar --</option>
                        <?php
                        $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM casa order by nombre_ca asc");

                        while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                            echo '<option value="' . $valores['id_casa'] . '">' . $valores['nombre_ca'] . '</option>';
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>                                                 
                </div> 
                <span class="help-block" id="error"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">    
                <label for="valor_apostado" class="form-control-label">Valor Apostado *</label>
                <div class="input-group">    
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></i>
                    </span> 
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="valor_apostado" name="valor_apostado" placeholder="" required="true">                                                    
                </div>
                <span class="help-block" id="error"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>                               
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Registrar">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span> Cerrar</button>
</form>
```

El código utilizado para la validación es este:

```js
// JavaScript Validation For Registration Page

$('document').ready(function ()
{
    var combb = / /;
    $.validator.addMethod("combo", function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || combb.test(value);
    });

    var nameregex = /[0-9]/;

    $.validator.addMethod("validvalorapos", function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || nameregex.test(value);
    });

    $("#myform").validate({
        rules:
                {
                    id_casa: {
                        required: true,
                        combo: true,
                    },
                    valor_apostado: {
                        required: true,
                        validvalorapos: true,
                        minlength: 4
                    },
                },
        messages:
                {                    
                    id_casa: {
                        required: "Seleccione una casa de Apuesta",
                        combo: "Seleccione una casa de Apuesta",
                    },
                    valor_apostado: {
                        required: "Ingrese el Valor Apostado",
                        validvalorapos: "Sólo se pueden Ingresar Números",
                        minlength: "Su Nombre es Demasiado Corto"
                    },
                },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').find('.help-block').html(error.html());
        },
        highlight: function (element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
        },
        unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
            $(element).closest('.form-group').find('.help-block').html('');
        },
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Después de tanto  buscar la solución para mi caso fue hacer unos cambios en las siguientes lineas.

```html
<option value="0">-- Seleccionar --</option>
por
<option value="">-- Seleccionar --</option>
```

Y el código de validación lo cambie por este:

```js
$("#myform").validate({
    rules:
            {
                id_casa: {
                    required: true,
                    number: true,
                },
                valor_apostado: {
                    required: true,
                    number: true,
                    min: 2000
                },
            },
    messages:
            {
                id_casa: {
                    required: "Seleccione una casa de Apuesta",
                },
                valor_apostado: {
                    required: "Ingrese el Valor Apostado",
                    number: "Sólo se pueden Ingresar Números",
                    min: "La Apuesta Debe Ser Mayor a $2000"
                },
            },
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').find('.help-block').html(error.html());
    },
    highlight: function (element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
        $(element).closest('.form-group').find('.help-block').html('');
    },
});
```

Los cambios son debido a que en el select sólo son números porque es el id de otra tabla, por eso agregue el number:true; para que valide que sea sólo números y debido a eso en el  al value le quito el 0 y lo dejo vacío paraque al validar detecte que no es de tipo número y muestre el mensaje.